# Action 'firebase_app_distribution' not available, run `fastlane actions` to get a full list

Tags: react-native, rubygems, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

```
❯ bundle exec fastlane run firebase_app_distribution
[✔]  
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                           Used plugins                                            |
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Plugin                             | Version | Action                                             |
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-badge              | 1.1.0   | add_badge                                          |
| fastlane-plugin-versioning_android | 0.1.0   | android_get_version_name android_set_version_code  |
|                                    |         | android_set_version_name android_get_version_code  |
| fastlane-plugin-android_sdk_update | 1.0.0   | android_sdk_update                                 |
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+


[!] Action 'firebase_app_distribution' not available, run `fastlane actions` to get a full list
```

I had no problems until 2 weeks ago. I could not find what affect it. does not appear in the list of "Used plugins" I can see the error with this command.

```
 ❯ bundle exec fastlane run fenter code hereirebase_app_distribution
```

I have this in fastlane/Pluginfile >>> gem 'fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution'
and i can see the plugin in tmp-fastlane-ci-bundle/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution

I have tried the following solutions

```
❯ sudo gem uninstall fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution
❯ gem install fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution --user-install
```

these doesn't work

```
❯ sudo chmod -R a+r /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-
0.1.4
chmod: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution-0.1.4: 
No such file or directory

❯ bundle exec fassudo chmod -R a+r /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-
firebase_app_distribution-0.1.4

bundler: command not found: fassudo
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late but for others that run into this issue: run `fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution` to add that plugin to fastlane